# WPF designer System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I have a WPF Window which calls a class library connected to a WCF Web Service.
The constructor of this Window calls the class library to get some data.

Everything is working fine when i run the solution, but when I try to open my Window in design mode, I'm getting this error:

Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'FinancesService.IAccountingService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

I have tried google, but it only says my problem is the config file, but I do have the  config in my main project.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerproperties.getisindesignmode.aspx) to detect design mode, and avoid attempting to call your web service.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It was so annoying because VS threw an exception everytime I opened that window in design mode.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio does execute your code (at least the ctor) of your control when you drop your control from the designer into some form. When your control is instantated by VS and your code does contain some code to connect to a remote endpoint you will get this exception because your control assumes as hosting process your "normal" process.

The easiest thing is to check in your ctor for the executing process. If it is devenv.exe then you can skip the wcf connect call to be able to display your control. You should take care that no follow up exceptions do happen but that should be an easy task now.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution seems to be to execute the WCF service call from the Loaded event handler of your WPF window, as a bonus it will make your application seem more responsive.